# Is there a safe way to autofill values into a lookup field

Tags: lookup

I have junction object called Application and its related to contact and custom object postion. We also have a interview object which has a lookup to Application. position and contact.

When i click the new Interview button from application object the Application id get auto filled which is standard. Since i already know the position and contact from Application object is there a safe way to pull values from application object and autofill.

I know the url hack, which is not supported and i want to use it appexchange package.

Just want to see if anyone has a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You could make Position and Contact read-only on the Interview page layout and then use an apex trigger to fill those lookups with the values derived from the related Application record.

Comment: Yeah, a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as Chatter is enabled for Application, you can use a [publisher action](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm) (a create action in this case) to do all this with just a few clicks, no code needed.